# Parse dates from before the year 1000

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

Consider the following example:

```
from datetime import datetime


FMT = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"

original_date = datetime(1,1,1)

s = original_date.strftime(FMT)  # This is '1-01-01T00:00:00'
```

When I now try to parse that string back into a datetime with the exact format I used to serialize it in the first place, a `ValueError` is thrown at me:

```
datetime.strptime(s, FMT)
```

> ValueError: time data '1-01-01T00:00:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'

However

```
datetime.strptime('0001-01-01T00:00:00', FMT)
```

works as expected.
I would have expected `strptime` to be able to handle whatever `strftime` produces. I always regarded those functions to be the inverse of each other.

Why does `original_date.strftime(FMT)` not result in a zero-padded year? Is there any reason for this inconsistency?

Comment: What Python version is this? I get '0001-01-01T00:00:00' in Python 3.6.

Comment: `%Y` matches `Year with century as a decimal number.` (i.e. 4 digits); `%y` matches `Year without century as a zero-padded decimal number.` (but that is still 2 digits)... this does not answer your question. but `strptime` will be able to reverse everything `strftime` generates.

Comment: @SimeonVisser That's strange, I am on Python 3.6 as well. What's your patch version?

Comment: @karlson: I'm running Python 3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5050, Mar 21 2017, 01:21:04).

Comment: @SimeonVisser And you're absolutely positive that `from datetime import datetime; datetime(1,1,1).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")` yields `'0001-01-01T00:00:00'`? I am on 3.6.1 as well and that line definitely returns `'1-01-01T00:00:00'`

Comment: @karlson: yes but I'm running Mac OS X. I think it's this issue that's the problem here: https://bugs.python.org/issue13305.

Comment: @SimeonVisser Lovely, that seems to be the problem exactly! I am on Linux and`%4Y` works for serialization (as mentioned [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue13305#msg257397)). If you care to make an answer out of that, I'd be happy to accept.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The results for `%Y` are not consistent across platforms. On Mac OS X it'll return `0001` but on Linux it returns `1`.

On Linux you can use `%4Y` to produce `0001` as year value.

This is a known issue: https://bugs.python.org/issue13305.

The documentation for `strftime()` and `strptime()` also states:

> The full set of format codes supported varies across platforms, because Python calls the platform C library’s strftime() function, and platform variations are common. To see the full set of format codes supported on your platform, consult the strftime(3) documentation.

Comment: Note: `strptime()` is implemented in pure Python and it is portable. On the other hand, `strftime()` (as the quote says) may use C strftime (the behavior is platform-dependent).